# Android Studio: "NullPointerException" when i load url into webview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

(I have to mention that i still beginner in android dev and my English may be somehow bad..)

I am working on an application for my study purpose and my problem is that every time I try to load a URL into a WebView the app crashes and the following log is noticed:

```
04-06 01:50:06.951  32474-32474/isitcom.isitcomexpress E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: isitcom.isitcomexpress, PID: 32474
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{isitcom.isitcomexpress/isitcom.isitcomexpress.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void isitcom.isitcomexpress.NavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(int, android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout)' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2689)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2756)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5940)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1389)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1184)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void isitcom.isitcomexpress.NavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(int, android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout)' on a null object reference
            at isitcom.isitcomexpress.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:46)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6283)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2642)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2756)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5940)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1389)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1184)
```

I use a drawer(the ready one from Android studio) to navigate between layouts and the webviw needed is situated in **Layout1_accueil.XML** attached to **menu1_accueil.java** code:

```
package isitcom.isitcomexpress;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;

/**
 * Created by Malek Boubakri on 13/03/2015.
 */
public class menu1_accueil extends Fragment{
    View rootview;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle setInitialSavedState){
        rootview=inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout1_accueil,container,false);
        //set up webview
        WebView webView = (WebView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        return rootview;
    }
}
```

i think **MainActivity.java** can be the source of error code:

```
package isitcom.isitcomexpress;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
        implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

    /**
     * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.
     */
    private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

    /**
     * Used to store the last screen title. For use in {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
     */
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    public static WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        mTitle = getTitle();

        // Set up the drawer.
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
                R.id.navigation_drawer,(DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));

    }

    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment objFragment=null;

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                objFragment = new menu1_accueil();
                break;
            case 1:
                objFragment = new menu2_etudiant();
                break;
            case 2:
                objFragment = new menu3_enseignant();
                break;
            case 3:
                objFragment = new menu4_ressources();
                break;
        }

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        assert fragmentManager != null;
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, objFragment)
                .commit();
    }

    public void onSectionAttached(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
                break;
            case 1:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
                break;
            case 2:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section3);
                break;
            case 3:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section4);
                break;
        }
    }

    public void restoreActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
            // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
            // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
            // decide what to show in the action bar.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            restoreActionBar();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);
            ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(
                    getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
        }
    }

}
```

Or may be in **NavigationDrawerFragment.java** code:

```
package isitcom.isitcomexpress;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Fragment used for managing interactions for and presentation of a navigation drawer.
 * See the <a href="https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#Interaction">
 * design guidelines</a> for a complete explanation of the behaviors implemented here.
 */
public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment {

    /**
     * Remember the position of the selected item.
     */
    private static final String STATE_SELECTED_POSITION = "selected_navigation_drawer_position";

    /**
     * Per the design guidelines, you should show the drawer on launch until the user manually
     * expands it. This shared preference tracks this.
     */
    private static final String PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER = "navigation_drawer_learned";

    /**
     * A pointer to the current callbacks instance (the Activity).
     */
    private NavigationDrawerCallbacks mCallbacks;

    /**
     * Helper component that ties the action bar to the navigation drawer.
     */
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerListView;
    private View mFragmentContainerView;

    private int mCurrentSelectedPosition = 0;
    private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;
    private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;

    public NavigationDrawerFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Read in the flag indicating whether or not the user has demonstrated awareness of the
        // drawer. See PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER for details.
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        mUserLearnedDrawer = sp.getBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, false);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mCurrentSelectedPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION);
            mFromSavedInstanceState = true;
        }

        // Select either the default item (0) or the last selected item.
        selectItem(mCurrentSelectedPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        // Indicate that this fragment would like to influence the set of actions in the action bar.
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mDrawerListView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
        mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                selectItem(position);
            }
        });
        mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActionBar().getThemedContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                android.R.id.text1,
                new String[]{
                        getString(R.string.title_section1),
                        getString(R.string.title_section2),
                        getString(R.string.title_section3),
                        getString(R.string.title_section4),
                }));
        mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);
        return mDrawerListView;
    }

    public boolean isDrawerOpen() {
        return mDrawerLayout != null && mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mFragmentContainerView);
    }

    /**
     * Users of this fragment must call this method to set up the navigation drawer interactions.
     *
     * @param fragmentId   The android:id of this fragment in its activity's layout.
     * @param drawerLayout The DrawerLayout containing this fragment's UI.
     */
    public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout) {
        mFragmentContainerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
        mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;

        // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
        // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
        // between the navigation drawer and the action bar app icon.
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                getActivity(),                    /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,                    /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,             /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.navigation_drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
        ) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) {
                    return;
                }

                getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) {
                    return;
                }

                if (!mUserLearnedDrawer) {
                    // The user manually opened the drawer; store this flag to prevent auto-showing
                    // the navigation drawer automatically in the future.
                    mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
                    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
                    sp.edit().putBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, true).apply();
                }

                getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };

        // If the user hasn't 'learned' about the drawer, open it to introduce them to the drawer,
        // per the navigation drawer design guidelines.
        if (!mUserLearnedDrawer && !mFromSavedInstanceState) {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }

        // Defer code dependent on restoration of previous instance state.
        mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        });

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
        mCurrentSelectedPosition = position;
        if (mDrawerListView != null) {
            mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
        }
        if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }
        if (mCallbacks != null) {
            mCallbacks.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mCallbacks = (NavigationDrawerCallbacks) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException("Activity must implement NavigationDrawerCallbacks.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mCallbacks = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION, mCurrentSelectedPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Forward the new configuration the drawer toggle component.
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // If the drawer is open, show the global app actions in the action bar. See also
        // showGlobalContextActionBar, which controls the top-left area of the action bar.
        if (mDrawerLayout != null && isDrawerOpen()) {
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.global, menu);
            showGlobalContextActionBar();
        }
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_example) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Actualisation...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * Per the navigation drawer design guidelines, updates the action bar to show the global app
     * 'context', rather than just what's in the current screen.
     */
    private void showGlobalContextActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
    }

    private ActionBar getActionBar() {
        return ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
    }

    /**
     * Callbacks interface that all activities using this fragment must implement.
     */
    public static interface NavigationDrawerCallbacks {
        /**
         * Called when an item in the navigation drawer is selected.
         */
        void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position);
    }
}
```

may my problem can seen easy for some genuis but am just a beginer and if this app dont run it will effect my mark badly :'(
please post any information can help me and i will be thankful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you webview is not located in R.layout.activity_main then you won't be able to find it using `WebView webView = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView1);`.

If it's placed into `R.layout.layout1_accueil` you will probably want to find it and use it from `menu1_accueil` fragment you have.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle setInitialSavedState){
    rootview=inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout1_accueil,container,false);
    WebView webView = (WebView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    return rootview;
}
```

Comment: yes, it is located in **R.layout.layout1_accueil** but how can i use there ?
even i try this another error accured:

04-06 01:27:06.882      731-731/isitcom.isitcomexpress E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{isitcom.isitcomexpress/isitcom.isitcomexpress.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
           ...
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at isitcom.isitcomexpress.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:53)
...

Comment: If you want it to load a website on fragment layout creation than just use it as you did before: `WebView webView = (WebView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.webView1); webView.loadUrl("...")`. Now you have a new problem that I will try to figure out :)

Comment: I will use the new way code you just give me.. and wait if the other new problem can be solved

Comment: You didn't post the full stacktrace for the second problem, but I guess it's because `mNavigationDrawerFragment` is null. If you have this fragment in your activity's XML layout then don't use `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById()` to find it, it's for another case. Just use findViewById(). @MalekBoubakri

Comment: I dont post the fullstacktrace because of the caracters limit in comment and i will post it for u if this last mantioned idea don't work..

Comment: i do repost the full stacktrace of the error in the top in the place of the old one.. and i don't get where or what should i do to run your last solution!

Comment: Ok, no worries. Let's try substitute `mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);` for `mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)this.findViewById(R.id.navigation_drawer);`. Just tell me how this works out.

Comment: the part after "=" is underlined in red zigzag line and an error say:
Error:(43, 80) error: inconvertible types
required: NavigationDrawerFragment
found:    View

Comment: Yeah, sorry, you were right. Your first option, before substitution, should work. But do you have the fragment itself in the `R.layout.activity_main` layout? There should be a tag `<fragment>` pointing to your `NavigationDrawerFragment` class.

Comment: Yes, in the **R.layout.activity_main** i have the tag:
<fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:name="isitcom.isitcomexpress.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

Comment: Problem resolved after i reboot my pc i dont know how but today i retry and everything goes fine.. thanks to @Android777