# NullPointerException on Activity onCreate

Tags: java, android, drawerlayout, navigation-drawer

I'm getting this error and I don't know why.  This same code was working before; the problem started occuring after an update at some point.

Stack trace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.domain.appname, PID: 17964
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.domain.appname/com.domain.appname.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.domain.appname.NavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(int, android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2441)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:162)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5431)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:914)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:707)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.domain.appname.NavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(int, android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout)' on a null object reference
    at com.domain.appname.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6056)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2332)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2441) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:162) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5431) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:914) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:707)
```

Here's the offending code in MainActivity.java:

```
...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG){ Log.d(TAG, "Created in debug mode"); }

    NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
        getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);

    // Set up the drawer.
    Log.d(TAG, "Setting up drawer");
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp( // Line 40
        R.id.navigation_drawer,
        (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
    );

...
```

I've found two questions that seem to have similar problems.  (Here's [the first](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29491567/3006854) and [the second](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29463640/3006854))  The first doesn't seem relevant, and the second is unanswered.

I'm baffled.  `drawer_layout` and `navigation_drawer` do **not** throw "symbol unresolved" errors.  Like I said, this all used to work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are never calling `Activity.setContentView(int)`. This is how it should be:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_containing_drawer);

    // Rest.
}
```

Comment: Yup, looks like I dropped that vital line when I added the `Created in debug mode`.  I hope this helps others (so I can feel less idiotic).